# Futsal (erro) - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bom pessoal, estou fazendo um código de futsal e estou tendo certos obstáculos com ele. Atualmente, estou estudando Python e pela primeira vez aplicando POO, então preciso que vocês me deem uma luz de como prosseguir aqui, já que tentei alguns jeitos e não foi, ao menos links para ajuda rs.

## python

```
class Pessoa():
    def __init__(self, nome, sobrenome, posicao):
        self.nome = str(nome)
        self.sobrenome = str(sobrenome)
        self.posicao = str(posicao)

class Cartola():
    def __init__(self, RB, DD, DP, A, F, G, I, PP, PE, FC, GC, CA, CV, FS):
        self.RB = float(RB * 1.5)
        self.DD = float(DD * 3)
        self.DP = float(DP * 7)
        self.A = float(A * 5)
        self.F = float(F * 1.5)
        self.G = float(G * 8)
        self.I = float(I * -0.5)
        self.PP = float(PP * -4)
        self.PE = float(PE * -0.3)
        self.FC = float(FC * -0.5)
        self.GC = float(GC * -5)
        self.CA = float(CA * -2)
        self.CV = float(CV * -5)
        self.FS = float(FS * 0.5)

class Goleiro(Cartola):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(DD, DP, PE, FC, CA, CV, FS)

    def getPontosGol(self):
        pontos = self.RB + self.DD + self.DP + self.PE + self.FC + self.CA + self.CV + self.FS
        return pontos

class Jogador(Cartola):
    def __init__(self, posicao, RB, A, F, G, I, PP, PE, FC, GC, CA, CV, FS):
        super().__init__(RB, A, F, G, I, PP, PE, FC, GC, CA, CV, FS)

    def getPontosJog(self):
        pontos = self.RB + self.A + self.F + self.G + self.I + self.PP + self.PE + self.FC + self.GC + self.CA + self.CV + self.FS
        return pontos

lista_team = []
listaTimeUm = []
listaTimeDois = []

def cadastroGoleiro():
    name_team = input('Digite o nome do seu time: \n')
    lista_team.append(name_team)
    
    # Cadastro Goleiro
    print('--- Cadastrando o Goleiro ! ---\n')
    nomeCompletoGoleiro = input('Insira o nome completo do Goleiro: ')
    separado = nomeCompletoGoleiro.split(' ')

    defesaDificil = input('Digite a quantidade de defesas difíceis: ')
    defesaPenalti = input('Digite a quantidade de defesas de pênalti: ')
    passeErrado = input('Digite a quantidade de passes errados: ')
    faltaCometida = input('Digite a quantidade de faltas cometidas: ')
    cartaoAmarelo = input('Digite a quantidade de cartões amarelos: ')
    cartaoVermelho = input('Digite a quantidade de cartões vermelhos: ')
    faltaSofrida = input('Digite a quantidade de faltas sofridas: ')

    pessoal = Pessoa(separado[0], separado[1], 'Goleiro')
    goleiro = Goleiro(defesaDificil, defesaPenalti, passeErrado, faltaCometida, cartaoAmarelo, cartaoVermelho, faltaSofrida)

    listaTimeUm.append(goleiro.getPontosGol().pontos)
        
cont = 0
pontosTotalJog = 0
nomeCompletoJogador = []
posicao = []
jogador = []
pessoa = []

def cadastroJogador():

    while cont != 4:
        print('--- Cadastrando o Jogador ! ---')

        full_name = input('Insira o nome completo do jogador: ')
        nomeCompletoJogador[cont].append(full_name)

        position = input('Insira a posição do jogador: ')
        posicao[cont].append(position)

        # Perguntas do jogador !
        roubadaBola = input('Digite a quantidade de roubadas de bola: ')
        assistencia = input('Digite a quantidade de assistências: ')
        finalizacao = input('Digite a quantidade de finalizações: ')
        gol = input('Digite a quantidade de gols: ')
        impedimento = input('Digite a quantidade impedimentos: ')
        penaltiPerdido = input('Digite a quantidade de pênaltis perdidos: ')
        passeErrado = input('Digite a quantidade de passes errados: ')
        faltaCometida = input('Digite a quantidade de faltas cometidas: ')
        golContra = input('Digite a quantidade de gols contras: ')
        cartaoAmarelo = input('Digite a quantidade de cartões amarelos: ')
        cartaoVermelho = input('Digite a quantidade de cartões vermelhos: ')
        faltaSofrida = input('Digite a quantidade de faltas sofridas: ')

        pessoa[cont] = Pessoa(separado[0], separado[1], posicao[cont])
        jogador[cont] = Jogador(posicao[cont], roubadaBola, assistencia, finalizacao, gol, impedimento, penaltiPerdido, passeErrado, faltaCometida, golContra, cartaoAmarelo, cartaoVermelho, faltaSofrida)
    
        listaTimeUm.append(jogador[cont].getPontosJog().pontos)

        cont += 1

cadastroGoleiro()
cadastroJogador()
```

Este código está gerando este erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python37\Scripts\futsal.py", line 105, in <module>
   cadastroGoleiro()
  File "C:\Python37\Scripts\futsal.py", line 62, in cadastroGoleiro
    goleiro = Goleiro(defesaDificil, defesaPenalti, passeErrado, 
faltaCometida, cartaoAmarelo, cartaoVermelho, faltaSofrida)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 8 were given
```

- O module estou procurando para saber que tipo de erro é, mas parece ser algo em relação a chamar a função no fim, mas não entendi o quê.
- O da linha 62 foi sobre eu ter instanciado na classe Goleiro o meu objeto goleiro com as respostas que recebi das perguntas que fiz nos inputs, mas não entendi porque ele quer que eu gere apenas e 1 argumento sendo que preciso de 8. Estou errando na utilização do super() na função **init** da classe Goleiro?

PS: ainda nem consegui executar a função do Jogador por tal erro.

Answer (score 0):

> não entendi porque ele quer que eu gere apenas e 1 argumento sendo que
>   preciso de 8

Essa é a idea, mas o seu código está dizendo que o `__init__` do `Goleiro` recebe apenas 1 argumento, então passar 8 argumentos resulta num erro.

Repare que ele está assim

```
class Goleiro(Cartola):
    # recebe apenas self, implicitamente
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(DD, DP, PE, FC, CA, CV, FS)
```

Quando a ideia era ser assim

```
class Goleiro(Cartola):
    def __init__(self, DD, DP, PE, FC, CA, CV, FS):
        super().__init__(DD, DP, PE, FC, CA, CV, FS)
```

Em nota, `Cartola` espera muito mais argumentos do que o que o `Goleiro` recebe. Mesmo que o `Goleiro` não utilize esses atributos `A`, `F`, `G`, `I`, `PP`..., você ainda deveria inicializa-los se vai herdar de `Cartola`

```
class Goleiro(Cartola):
    def __init__(self, DD, DP, PE, FC, CA, CV, FS):
        super().__init__(0, DD, DP, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, PE, FC, 0, CA, CV, FS)
```